# Magento2 : How to deal with zip files

Tags: magento2, zip

I need to be able to treat zip files programmatically.

In magento 1.9 I was doing :

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

        if ($zip->open($Zippath) === TRUE) 
        {
            $zip->addFile($Filepath, $Filename);
            $zip->addFile($FilepathL, "toto.txt");
            $zip->close();
            return TRUE;    }
```

How can I do the same in magento 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this the same way

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open($Zippath) === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile($Filepath, $Filename);
    $zip->addFile($Filepath, "toto.txt");
    $zip->close();
    return TRUE; 
}
```

Comment: I have just tested and get an error on $zip->close(); : Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Is a directory. For $FilePath i have /foo/bar and $FileName toto.txt

Comment: Sorry, was due to typo error... working well. answer apporved

Answer (score 11):

Alternativaly **you can use the Magento framework class of M2 called `Magento\Framework\Archive\Zip`** and call the `pack()` method.

For example, if you injected the class and assigned it to the `$zipArchive` variable you can do:

```
$this->zipArchive->pack($source, $destination);
```

Comment: Does this work with AWS S3 Remote Storage. I am getting some errors when unpacking a zip.

Comment: The return of \ZipArchive::open() is 9 for me. Which is ZIP_ER_NOENT .

Comment: Seems we cannot directly perform operations on zip file inside S3.

Answer (score 4):

Its basically a `php class`. It has nothing to do with Magento. However you can check the implementation is still like the same.

> Here is the class http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

And here is the implementation in Magento2.

If you open

> lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Archive\Zip.php you will find this

```
public function pack($source, $destination)
    {
        $zip = new \ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($destination, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
        $zip->addFile($source);
        $zip->close();
        return $destination;
    }
```